# How to create multiple MUI Popovers in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Please note! I am new to both React and MUI, and **I find the MUI documentation *very hard* to understand.** So any helpful tips or deeper explanations are greatly welcomed :) I did not intend to jump right away to using MUI but I need to use popovers for my first React project.

**My Problem:**

I am trying to create a page that has multiple MUI Popover elements.
After I created my first Popover with it's respective contents, whenever I try to create another Popover, the first one gets overwritten by the new one.

**What and why do I have to include to create multiple MUI Popover Components?**

I've included a code snippet omitting unimportant stuff:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Popover, Typography, createTheme } from '@mui/material';

export default function Projects() {

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
return(
    <div>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        >
        <p> Popover content here lol</p>
       </Popover>
    </div>
);
}
```

Thank you in advance. Just looking to acquire new knowledge!

Comment: Edited your question a bit-- don't call your question dumb, we all need to ask questions to learn! Have you tried simply having two different popover components (i.e., two <Popover/> definitions, one under the other), each with their own anchorEl, id, etc? What issues did you run into.

Comment: Could you also share the code where you call `handleClick`?